# Servlet include swallows HTTP headers in Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I have a servlet that does a request dispatcher include of another servlet.

The included servlet sets headers that I would like to read in the *including* servlet. So I pass in a custom HTTPResponse object in the include() method which captures all feedback activity from the servlet.

The problem is that the headers are not being set in my custom response. I've run in debug and examined what looks like Tomcat wrapping my custom response object with its own response object. The setHeader calls go to this wrapping class and never propagate to my custom response object.

I imagine Tomcat does this to protect the client from headers being set in the wrong place. The funny thing is that the same approach works the way I'd expect in Jetty.

It's been a while since I've done Servlets seriously so I'm struggling a bit here. I'm trying to figure out how to read the response headers from a servlet that's invoked via dispatcher.include().

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**From the Servlet specifications section SRV.8.3:**

*The include method of the RequestDispatcher interface may be called at any time.
The target servlet of the include method has access to all aspects of the request
object, but its use of the response object is more limited.*

*It can only write information to the ServletOutputStream or Writer of the
response object and commit a response by writing content past the end of the
response buffer, or by explicitly calling the flushBuffer method of the
ServletResponse interface.*

*It cannot set headers or call any method that affects
the headers of the response. Any attempt to do so* ***must be ignored***.

How about setting your values for the calling servlet in request scope, with `request.setAttribute(...)` and then reading it from there once you return? Could that work?

Comment: Thank you for clarifying the behavior for me. You know I thought about using request.setAttribute(). That would work and I was reserving that as plan B as it's not optimal in the sense of D.R.Y. I need access to the content-type and content length to propagate to the including servlet. Using request attributes forces redundancy. Still, the included servlet *is* in need of refactoring. Thanks again!

Comment: If I converted my *including* servlet to a Filter would that work? I mean is it a spec violation to write headers in a servlet invoked by a Filter?

Comment: +1 Correct. I have tested it on _WildFly Full 9.0.1.Final_, _Apache Tomcat/6.0.29_, _Apache Tomcat/7.0.47_, and _Jetty-9.3.3.v20150827_, and changing headers in the included response is not possible with any of them (as expected). It's a long time since this question was posted, so no surprises here. I just wanted to double-check it.

Comment: By the way, "_How about setting your values for the calling servlet in request scope [...]_"... I also have tested this after including an empty jsp, and this also works.

Comment: But for the record, I also have tested with a bigger jsp and apparently changing the response only works if it hasn't already been committed. This would explain it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2030908/413020