# ShallowEtagHeaderFilter does not work under WAS8 app server

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, websphere, websphere-8

`org.springframework.web.filter.ShallowEtagHeaderFilter` is unable to set response header under WAS8 application server stating "***WARNING: Cannot set header. Response already committed***". However this works fine when tested under Tomcat server. `ShallowEtagHeaderFilter` is indeed wrapping the original response to delay the writing of response body, but still the response comes as committed after the filter chain's execution. Is this a possible websphere bug? Any suggestion / workaround to overcome this issue is welcome.

Comment: have u checked this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030152/srtservletres-w-warning-cannot-set-header-response-already-committed

Comment: @Sajith Yes, I have seen that answer. But ShallowEtagHeaderFilter is wrapping the actual response, so that nothing is written into the response until ShallowEtagHeaderFilter finishes adding the response header.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I solved this issue by overriding `ServletResponse.flushBuffer` method. Under WAS8 `flushBuffer` is getting called prematurely. Passing a `HttpServletResponseWrapper` with a no-operation `flushBuffer` method to `ShallowEtagHeaderFilter` did the trick.

```
public class HttpCacheFilter extends ShallowEtagHeaderFilter {

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {

        HttpCacheResponseWrapper responseWrapper = new HttpCacheResponseWrapper(response);
        super.doFilterInternal(request, responseWrapper, filterChain);
    }

    private static class HttpCacheResponseWrapper extends HttpServletResponseWrapper {

        public HttpCacheResponseWrapper(HttpServletResponse response) {
            super(response);
        }

        @Override
        public void flushBuffer() throws IOException {
            // NOOP
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you sir, are a godsend. I hate opening PMRs with IBM, and this just solves this problem outright.

Answer (score 1):

i think the above problem can be resolved by adding this custom property

com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.invokeFlushAfterService = false

Answer (score -1):

I was using `extremecomponents` jar file using

```
chain.doFilter(request, new ExportResponseWrapper((HttpServletResponse) response))
```

faced "Cannot set header. Response already committed" in WAS8 .

by

```
    @Override
    public void flushBuffer() throws IOException {

    }
```

in ExportResponseWrapper class , saved my life.

Thanks a lot ... :)