# Response already committed when using Spring 3.x on Websphere 8.5

Tags: java, spring, http-headers, websphere, servlet-filters

When adding / updating a response header after the request has been processed I get the following warning:

```
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srt.SRTServletResponse setHeader SRVE8094W: WARNING: Cannot set header. Response already committed.
```

I am trying to manipulate the header by calling `httpServletResponse.setHeader()` or `httpServletResponse.addHeader()` from within a servlet filter after `filterChain.doFilter()` or by postHandle code spring interceptor.

I have encountered this problem while running my webapp using spring 3.x on websphere 8.5.

The problem is not reproduced on tomcat 7.0 therefore my guess is that it is Websphere related.
The problem is not reproduced in a pure servlet app therefore my guess is that it is Spring related.

I am familiar with

[ShallowEtagHeaderFilter does not work under WAS8 app server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13266744/shallowetagheaderfilter-does-not-work-under-was8-app-server)

and with

[Cannot set header in JSP. Response already committed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030152/srtservletres-w-warning-cannot-set-header-response-already-committed)

but I am looking for a "cleaner" solution.

Can anybody help me on this?

Comment: You could modify your filter to wrap the `HttpServletResponse` object with your own that doesn't flush the headers and `OutputStream` until some specific time, eg. when your filter returns from `doFilter()`.

Comment: Thank, but currently I am not looking for a workaround, and since I think it is a Spring-Websphere issue I still hope there is a solution for this.

Comment: Can't you set the header before the `doFilter()`?

Comment: I wouldn't ask if I could...    :-)

Comment: I have the same issue on Tomcat 7

Answer (score -1):

Websphere strictly follows the J2EE standard, hence whatever works in Tomcat need not necessarily work in Websphere. In my project, I got a lot of exception/errors which are particular for Websphere, but works as a charm in Tomcat. I suggest you to set the header in the controller. One other alternate is not to flush the output stream in the controller (if you have done it explicitly).